# PHP - Session array - prevent duplicate entrys

Tags: php, arrays, session

This one is really bugging me, and can not find a easy solution.

On a detail view of a product, i set the info to a session, maximum 4:

```
$_SESSION['recent'][] = array(
      'id' => $productimgfolder,
      'title' => $product['Product']['title'],
      'link' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
      'image' => 'img/products/'.$productimgfolder.'/'.$product['Product']['mainpicture']
    );
$_SESSION['recent'] = array_slice($_SESSION['recent'],-4);
```

This part works, if i output the session:
**edit image => this is wat happens if i reload the detail view**

[image]

The part i'am struggling with is, when i reload a detail view, the info in the session is duplicated.

How can i prevent this from happening?

I tried it with `in_array` & `array_unique`, i'am doing something wrong

Comment: Can't you specify a key for the array you're adding to $_SESSION['recent']? It is going to help you prevent duplicates

Comment: Please share the duplicated data or the keys that you find on reload

Comment: Please provide what you hope your session to look like after a refresh.

Comment: What if you have "A B C D" and then load "C" ... should it show "B C D C" or "A B C D"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy solution:

if the id is unique, you can do like this:

```
if(!array_key_exists ($productimgfolder, $_SESSION['recent']))
{
    $_SESSION['recent'][$productimgfolder] = array(
          'id' => $productimgfolder,
          'title' => $product['Product']['title'],
          'link' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
          'image' => 'img/products/'.$productimgfolder.'/'.$product['Product']['mainpicture']
        );
}

$_SESSION['recent']=array_slice($arr, -4, 4, true);
```

other wise you have to foreach the recent array and check for id in the loop...

Comment: You can't use custom key, because `array_slice` will overwrite them. Try it.

Comment: Why did someone rate down this answer? It's the proper way. @Kristiyan, last param of `array_slice` is the flag to preserve key

Comment: @Kristiyan I have updated the answer, this is how you can use array_slice

Comment: thx Ali, this solution works, its preventing duplacte entries.i learned from you.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I just tried your code and it's doesn't work. Now it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check isset

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['recent']))
{
        $_SESSION['recent'] = array()
 }
```

THEN YOU CAN CHECK IF SESSION IS EMPTY

```
if(empty($_SESSION['recent']))
 {
    //here you add your data
 }
```

because you are using array push, on page reload it adds data unless you check if session is empty. if yes you add data to your session.

Comment: its not about that the session exists, its about to prevent duplicate entries in the session.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution may be;

```
array_unshift($sessionArray, $singleArrayElement);
if (count($sessionArray) > 4) {
    array_pop($seassionArray);
};
```